# How to write in a specif db schema with gorm?

Tags: database, go, go-gorm

I am new at golang. I am trying to write in a specific database schema using GORM and database/sql package.
Here is my struct

```
type Person struct {
gorm.Model
Name                string    
Age                 int    
}
```

and my function to write in db is:

```
func writedb(){

psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+" password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", host, port, user, password, dbname)
    db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
        fmt.Println("Não conectou-se ao BANCO DE DADOS")
    }
    defer db.Close()

    db.AutoMigrate(&Person{})

    //t := time.Now()
    //ts := t.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")

    db.Create(&Person{Name : "alex", Age: 20})


}
```

My db is structured like this
databaseName
--schemaPeople
--schemaVehicle
--schemaPublic

When I compile, the data inserted goes to an new table in public schema, I want to insert an row in people schema. What am I doing wrong? Am I declaring the struct wrong? How I set the specific schema??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `gorm` you can denote the schema in the `TableName()` method of your struct, for example:

```
type Person struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func (Person) TableName() string {
    return "people.persons"
}
```

Comment: tiny question, is this because of the way a raw SQL query would translate ```select * from persons;``` as compared to ```select * from people.persons;```?